# Instance an element from a parent class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, parent, children

I have the following structure:

-PARENT

--CHILD

--CHILD

--CHILD

--CHILD

Pretty straight forward.  Now, I need the PARENT class to have a function such as createNewChild(id).  The PARENT element has the following that each CHILD must override:

```
Public MustOverride Function getId() As Integer
```

Now, is it possible to get a list of all available children of a parent at run time so that I can do this?  Sorry if this sounds confusing, I'm having a hard time explaining this.

Basically though, I want to be able to do the following:

```
Dim nParent as PARENT = PARENT.createNewChild(5)
```

Any ideas?  I'm using VB.net so any .net answers are acceptable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only thing that I could think of to keep track of the children of your parent class is by creating a list of children upon creation.

```
Class Parent
    Private Shared childList As New List(Of Child)()

    Public Sub CreateNewChild(id As Integer)
        Dim newChild As New Child(id)
        childList.Add(newChild)
        Return newChild
     End Sub

   Public Overridable Function GetID() As Integer
       Return 0
   End Function

   Public Shared Function GetAllChildren() As List(Of Child)
       Return childList
   End Function
End Class

Class Child Inherits Parent
    Private m_ID As Integer
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_ID
    End Get
    Set
        m_ID = Value
     End Set
End Property

Private Sub New(id As Integer)
    Me.ID = id
End Sub
End Class
```

Sorry about the code, I originally wrote it in C# and used an online converter to convert to VB.